# How i can except a column from select * in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, request, multiple-columns

I noticed that in mysql i can't make an except on selecting some columns, there is my request:

`SELECT * FROM plane as p JOIN type as t ON p.id=t.id;`

But this shows me all columns even the two columns **plane_id** and **type_id** that are equivalent, is there a request i can do to print just one of them and excepting the other ??

Comment: Never use `SELECT *`

Comment: i thaught to select just all columns i want to show, but in case there is a large columns i can't select them peer by peer